# Assigning a command BAT file environment variable via a perl script

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I have a batch file I'm running under cmd.exe window.  I want to look at a web config file and get a value.  I have no idea of the right way to do this, but I figure I can cheat by writing a perl script to do this - and returning the value to the batch file.

I'm looking for something that looks like:

set var1=(evaluate perl script)

How does one do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set var1=
echo var1=%var1%
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%q in (`perl -E"say 'foo'"`) do set var1=%%q
echo var1=%var1%
```

Use `%q` instead of `%%q` outside of a batch file.